# item menu: define a routerlink active by default when launching the application

Tags: angular, menu, routerlinkactive

It’s all in the title, I’d like the first item of my menu to take the
'primary' style of angular material.
Here is my code that works only when I clicked on a menu item

```
    <div class="menu">
        <div *ngFor="let itemFooterMenu of itemsFooterMenu; let indexItem = index">
            <a routerLink="{{ itemFooterMenu.utilRoute }}" routerLinkActive #rla="routerLinkActive" >
                
                <button class="mat-raised-button" mat-raised-button [color]="rla.isActive ? 'primary' : ''">
                    <div>
                        <mat-icon [color]="rla.isActive ? '' : 'primary'">{{ itemFooterMenu.matIcon }}</mat-icon>
                    </div>
                </button>
            </a>
        </div>
</div>
```

How can I do that ? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu">
  <div *ngFor="let itemFooterMenu of itemsFooterMenu; let indexItem = index;" >
    <a routerLink="{{ itemFooterMenu.utilRoute }}" routerLinkActive="active" #rla="routerLinkActive">
      <button class="mat-raised-button" mat-raised-button [color]="rla.isActive ? 'primary' : ''">
        <div>
          <mat-icon [color]="rla.isActive ? '' : 'primary'">{{ itemFooterMenu.matIcon }}</mat-icon>
        </div>
      </button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**TS**

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
}
```

After loading values to itemsFooterMenu,navigate to the first routerlink in the array

```
this.router.navigate([this.itemsFooterMenu[0].utilRoute]);
```